# Specific repositories for each entity and a database reader?

Tags: c#, sql

I am working on a small project for Uni. I currently have 3 entities: admin, user and article. I want to implement specific repositories for each of them.Now my question is: If i have data stored in a database (3 tables for each entity, no foreign key relationships or anything), is it more convenient to read data for each table in their specific repository and storing into lists or add another repository for reading the data and storing each in separate lists? Which is good practice? I have read articles on stackoverflow and others but I didn't get a very clear answer.

Another thing: I am working in Win Forms. I will need a LogIn window therefor i need a LogIn repository so i need data from clients and admins tables to verify usernames and passwords and such. Which way is simpler and more correct?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of having two tables one for Admin and the other for the normal user , I Suggest you use one table that have a Column called Role for example so while the user is logging , if his role is for example 'Admin' then he may go to somewhere to administrate the project (add / edit / delete) 
else : go somewhere else , and so on .

As for repository Issues , It helps improve performance when you separate each table repository in a separate class.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I was thinking of creating one user table for both clients and admin. Do you think i should read the data from tables in each repository according to each class/table or create another repo for reading and and storing data only?

Comment: Make it inside the same repository class